# How can I change from a sed to Perl statement in command line?

Tags: perl, sed, grep

I need to search a phrase in multi files and display the results on the screen.

```
grep "EMS" SCALE_*
| sed -e "s/SCALE_//" -e
"s/_main_.*log:/ /"
```

Since I am not get familiar with sed, I change it to Perl for convenient use.

```
grep "EMS" SCALE_*
| perl -e "s/SCALE_//" -e
"s/_main_.*log:/ /"
```

or

```
grep "EMS" SCALE_*
| perl -e "s/SCALE_//; s/_main_.*log:/ /"
```

However , the last one is compiled but returns nothing on the command line. 
Any suggestion for modifying my code.
Great thanks!

Comment: I suggest you learn sed, or perk, or both.  Very convenient languages.

Answer (score 8):

To use `perl`in the style of `sed` you should try the `-p`flag:

```
perl -p -e "s/SCALE_//;" -e "s/_main_.*log:/ /;"
```

From the explanation in [`perlrun`](http://search.cpan.org/~dapm/perl-5.10.1/pod/perlrun.pod):

> **-p**
>
> > causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed:
> >
> > ```
> > LINE:
> >   while (<>) {
> >     ...             # your program goes here
> >   } continue {
> >     print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
> >   }
> > ```

Answer (score 3):

You're not looping over the input lines with perl. Check out -p or -n in the perlrun man page.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use Perl, then try this entirely in Perl

```
while ( <> ){
    chomp;
    if ( $_ =~ /EMS/ ){
        s/SCALE_//g;
        s/main.*log://g;
        print $_."\n";
    }
}
```

on the command line

```
$ perl perl.pl SCALE_*
```

or this

```
$ perl -ne 'if (/EMS/){ s/SCALE_//g;s/main.*log://g; print $_} ;' SCALE_*
```